# audio tag on iPhone

Tags: html, audio, wav

I have the following in my html page:

```
<audio id="doink-wav" src="doink.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

And then I have this in my JavaScript:

```
var wav = $('#doink-wav')[0];
$('form').submit(function() {
    wav.play();
});
```

And it works in Chrome and Firefox, but not on my iPhone.

Comment: Oh wait a minute.  I heard it do it 1 time, but now it just pops almost imperceptibly.

Comment: what happens if you preceed the `wav.play();` with `wav.load();` (I know you're preloading, but might be worth a shot)

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues playing large WAV files before, prehaps you could convert the wav file to ACC or MP3. These file formats seem to play better on iOS. Chrome will be able to play ACC too and FireFox will fall back to WAV.

```
<audio id="doink-wav" preload="auto"> 
    <source src="doink.m4a"> 
    <source src="doink.wav"> 
</audio>
```